# Sync two offline masters when network available

Tags: mongodb

I have a use case where I need to set up two physical stations at a venue. Each station will be running a couple of app servers and a mongodb server.

I can't rely on the venue's internet access so I need my app to be able to work offline and "sync" the dbs every once in a while.

I initially thought about having two masters that would somehow sync with a remote one but TIL that master-master replication is not possible with mongodb.

I've read about the active-active approach, however, that won't let me write to a different shard when offline.

I'm running out of ideas, any recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

------ Update on what I'm trying to achieve:

I'm working with a venue that has two entrances. The idea is to be able to capture some information from people attending the events (name, email, etc). After getting registered we will print a name tag with some of the info.

Everything sounds pretty easy, however, if possible, I would like to not rely on the venue's network (internet). So that's where I started struggling figuring out whats the best approach. I guess what I want is being able to have a remote mongo but if the network goes down somehow keep saving records locally and send them to the remote mongo instance when network is available again.

Extra considerations:
- Events last a couple of days, some people lose their name tag overnight, they should be able to go to either of the entrances and get it reprinted. So we should be able to find their info even if they registered in entrance A but they are asking for a reprint in entrance B.

More questions:
- Am I overthinking it? Maybe venue's network + a 4G/LTE modem as a backup should be enough? I would prefer not relying on it tho.

Comment: What you described sounds like you have two apps that's writing to two different servers, and occasionally you wanted to "sync" the contents of the two servers. Is this correct? How are you dealing with conflicts? To me this sounds like a deliberate "split brain" scenario, is it not?

Comment: @kevinadi That is correct. I haven't started on the project yet. I'm trying to get informed on what would be the best approach but seems way more complicated than what I initially thought. In regards to conflicts, I could live with "most recent wins".

Comment: Unfortunately "Most recent wins" in a distributed system is not as simple as it sounds. Clocks could be skewed, network issues, client clocks not synced, etc etc. I think we should go back a step and understand what you're trying to achieve before discussing solutions. Please update the question with the use case, the situation you're facing, what you are trying to do in more detail, and what your app is supposed to do.

Comment: @kevinadi Thanks for taking the time responding. Updated the question with what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're overthinking things. Here's what I would do if faced with a similar situation:

From the description, it doesn't sound like the two sites need to be connected in real time at all. I would create a server on Entry A, another in Entry B, and consolidate their data each day after the day ended if required. This is because:

1. It's unlikely that one person will register in both sites within a single day. If they lost their tag on that day, I'll just tell them to go back to where they registered earlier and get it reprinted there. Worst case, you'll create a duplicate entry (should be obvious which is the duplicate since no one would lose their tag within seconds) but I would not anticipate hundreds of people all lost their tags within a day.
2. If the attendee lost their tag overnight, both servers will have synced data and should be able to reprint.
3. If you're concerned about the venue's Wifi access, just run cables from the server to the printing stations.

Personally, I would argue that the overnight sync is not really needed at all (see the likelihood of people registering twice). I would just collect the data from both servers after the event ended. That is, unless you have specific needs for the combined data from both entries during the 2nd day.

**Note:** please make sure you're running a minimum of 3-node replica set. Running a standalone instance for prod environment is not recommended. Hardware/disk corruption is a common event.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Could you point me in the right direction on where I can read about consolidating the data?

Comment: Not really, I was thinking about a simple consolidation like inserting all the data from one server to the other, nothing fancy about it.